# MySQL, order by multiple columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

I have two tables:

```
Table of Artists (tbl_artist):

artist_id - primary key
artist_name - has index   


Table of Albums (tbl_album):

album_id - primary key
album_artist_id - foreign key, has index
album_name - has index too
```

Tables have a lot of records on production server (artists - 60k, albums - 250k).

And on index page there is a list of albums, with pagination step = 50.
Albums are sorted by artist_name ASC, album_name ASC. So the simplified query is following:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_artist, tbl_album
WHERE album_artist_id = artist_id
ORDER BY artist_name, album_name
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Query is executing very long. Probably it's because of ordering by columns from different tables. When I leave only 1 ordering - query is executing immediately.

What is possible to do in such situation? Many thanks.

**Edit**:
explain:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys    | key     | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_album     | ALL    | album_artist_id  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                              | 254613 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_artist    | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY | 4       | db.tbl_album.album_artist_id      |      1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

explain with STRAIGHT_JOIN

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref                                | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_artist    | ALL  | PRIMARY         | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                               | 57553 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_album     | ref  | album_artist_id | album_artist_id | 4       | db.tbl_artist.artist_id            |     5 |                                 |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you show us what mysql tells you with "EXPLAIN SELECT...", please?

Comment: Have you tried the Answer of Hammerite in combination with your straight_join? That should be fast in my opinion. And by the way, what do you mean by very long? Seconds? Tens of seconds? Minutes?

Comment: @Argeman , yes, I have tried with straight_join and without - no increasing of speed, and explain doesn't change. By very long I mean 10-15 second with query like above. And 20-30 with real query (with other joins).

Comment: Okay, that is slow. The only thing that remains is to try to avoid reading so many rows from the first table. They might all be joined to the second one, so maybe a subquery that returns 10 artists joined to the album-table might be a solution?

Comment: But on the the site user can select range (simple pagination) [0-50], or [1000-1050] or even [20150-20200]. And of course the number of albums that artist have can be from 0 to .... I think it will be difficult to guarantee choosing correct range of artists to select.

Comment: That is the reason why i didn't make an answer out of it - it is not solving the problem. However, did you test the performance of it? Your problem is really anoiing, no answer is really solving it until now!

Answer (score 5):

You need an index of (`artist_name`, `artist_id`) and then (`album_artist_id`, `album_name`).  The reason is because your join is between `artist_id` and `album_artist_id`, so it has to perform the same join with the indexes to produce a final need index of (`artist_name`, `album_name`) for the sort.

You then need to change your order by to be: `ORDER BY artist_name, artist_id, album_name`. This is because there could be two `artist_name`'s that are the same, and this will cause it to order not as you are expecting. Also it will prevent it from using an index.

Using just indexes on `artist_name`, and `album_name` doesn't provide enough information to produce that sort, all you have is an ordered list of names with nothing to indicate how they connect to the other table.

Comment: I've tried that in a similar set up but MySQL was still using filesort ...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the index on `(album_artist_id)` to an index on `(album_artist_id, album_name)`.

Comment: That is surprising to me. I'm not sure what to suggest. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to watch for, if you do not have full where clause resolved by **index** on order by column, is how many rows you need to scan to resolve order by . If only 50 rows are examined to provide
10 rows of result set you’re in decent shape but if it is 5000 you might need to rethink your indexing.

Second thing you can do , is to increase the **sort_buffer_size** large

Comment: **sort_buffer_size** = 4 MB for now.
I agree with idea to rethink indexing, but I'm not sure if it's even achievable. Maybe with such kind of ordering it's impossible to achieve acceptable query speed?

Comment: @kasitan yes this is achievable. this will help you http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2010/05/09/how-to-tune-mysqls-sort_buffer_size/

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the columns you `order by`.

if you want to know why your query takes so long then have a look at  `EXPLAIN`. Example:

```
explain select * from your_table order by col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding indexes on columns that you sort by would be a fair shout. It will, yes, take more space in the server, but the execution would be at it's best. Read more about indexes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html or http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-index.php